# Securing applications rest with ambassador

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, ambassador

I have an application with rest api secured by ambassador, my filter required all requests to provide username and password in header. Now I want to add additional service that will use the same endpoint as the users. Since my other service does not act as a user, can I configure it with some sort of api key to use ambassador or od I need to create a service account and use username/password headers in requests?